# How to display navbar in mobile like sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, sidebar

I have a navbar in a desktop site, but I want it in mobilesite like a sidebar.
How to convert the navbar to sidebar in the mobile site?

```
     <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
       <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Site name</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="home">Home            <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="themes">
            <li><a href="../default/">Default</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">page 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Help</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#" target="_blank">username</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Please can you post your code in a jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QAgvj

convert this to sidebar

Comment: I dont really understand what you are asking for, do you want it to slide in from the right?

Comment: is it possible to convert this navbar to sidebar ?

Comment: elaborate the meaning of sidebar...?

Comment: see this website on mobile or small screen on desktop.
menu is convert to sidebar 
see this link...
http://dbushell.github.io/Responsive-Off-Canvas-Menu/step2.html

Comment: Your code already collapses the menu and makes it appear when you click the button with 3 lines. Are you asking how to make that menu slide in from the side instead of from the top?

Comment: Here you go: http://jsbin.com/hawakudu/3/edit Is that what you mean?

Comment: if i open this site in small screen (mobile, tablet, etc...) than it will display in sidebar, otherwise as it is.